# TeXShop Command Completion Indent

Tags: lists, indentation, texshop, auto-completion

In TeXShop, I am editing the CommandCompletion.txt file.  I simply need to add an indent (which I would normally use tab for) directly before `item`. Here is the line of code I am trying to modify:

```
\bite:=\begin{itemize}#RET#\item #INS##INS##RET#\end{itemize}
```

As it stands, it looks like this:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\item 
\end{itemize}
```

But I want:

```
\begin{itemize}
     \item 
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: press `tab` between `#RET#` and `\item` and save.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: @Symbol1 wanna make that an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As asked in comment)

Press tab between `#RET#` and `\item` and save. See that charming orange triangle?

[image]